# Lua not running script from cmd line

Tags: lua

```
why I am in this trying to figure out what I done wrong mess. As was mentioned before I deleted and started over. This is a fresh install of windows 11 about 4 days now. I did add the folders to my system path. And do not get the program that #1 back up company that starts with an A and ends with an S. When their file goes corrupt and it's like pretty much oh well. Not much. But here we go. Look at the photos. I am going to try and format this again. How the hell do you know what line this thing is bitching about. There is only 6 lines of code in this thing. The rest is my troubleshooting. ~~~
```

1. local x = math.pi
2. local r = 6
3. local Area2 = (x * r ^ 2)
4. local Area = Area2-Area2%0.01
5. print(Area = ..Area.. Oh Yea)

````
 
 *  Executing task in folder MA_scripts: lua54 c:\Users\iSpeedyG\OneDrive\Documents\MA_scripts\LuaUdemy\4_Variables_Expressions\circleArea.lua 
 
Area = 113.09 Oh Yea
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 
 
**"DEFAULT COMMAND PROMPT above"**  ALL THIS IN VSCODE

------------------------------------------------------------
*  Executing task in folder MA_scripts: lua54 c:\Users\iSpeedyG\OneDrive\Documents\MA_scripts\LuaUdemy\4_Variables_Expressions\circleArea.lua 
 
C:\lua\lua54.exe: cannot open c:UsersiSpeedyGOneDriveDocumentsMA_scriptsLuaUdemy4_Variables_ExpressionscircleArea.lua: No such file or directory
 
 *  The terminal process C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe --login, -c, lua54 c:\Users\iSpeedyG\OneDrive\Documents\MA_scripts\LuaUdemy\4_Variables_Expressions\circleArea.lua terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 
 
**"DEFAULT BASH PROMPT  above"** 

----------------------------------------------------------------
Next I added a file all the way in my c:\lua called just checking.lua. 1 line of code
 
1.  print(Trying to figure out why i cannot run a lua from cmd line. thinking it has someinthing to do with my docs folder now in one drive.)
 *  Executing task in folder MA_scripts: lua54 c:\lua\justchecking.lua 
 
C:\lua\lua54.exe: cannot open c:luajustchecking.lua: No such file or directory
 
 *  The terminal process C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe --login, -c, lua54 c:\lua\justchecking.lua terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

**"DEFAULT BASH PROMPT above"**   ```FROM BEFORE DIDNT CHANGE IT```

-----------------------------------------------------------------
*  Executing task in folder MA_scripts: lua54 c:\lua\justchecking.lua 
 
```*Trying to figure out why i cannot run a lua from cmd line. thinking it has someinthing to do with my docs folder now on one drive."*```

*  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

**"DEFAULT COMMAND PROMPT above"**  ```*"THESE FOUR above WERE WITH CTRL+SHIFT+B -->Terminal Menu--run, build, task"*```

---------------------------------------------------------------------
 
```"NOW JUST GOING TO TYPE THE COMMAND IN BOTH FROM PROMPT AND THEN LUA54 NOTE EVEN CHANGED DIRECTORY TO WHERE THE FILE IS DEFAULT FOLDER IS ACTUALLY SET TO MA_SCRIPTS SET FROM LOADED  WORKSPACE"```


c:\lua>lua54
Lua 5.4.2  Copyright (C) 1994-2020 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
lua justchecking.lua
stdin:1: syntax error near justchecking
justchecking.lua
stdin:1: attempt to index a nil value (global justchecking)
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
 os.exit()
 
c:\lua>  
**"DEFAULT COMMAND PROMPT above"**

-------------------------------------------------------------------
iSpeedyG@iSpeedyG-PC MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/MA_scripts
$ cd c:lua
 
iSpeedyG@iSpeedyG-PC MINGW64 /c/lua
$ dir
justchecking.lua  lua54.dll  lua54.exe  luac54.exe  wlua54.exe
 
iSpeedyG@iSpeedyG-PC MINGW64 /c/lua
$ lua justchecking.lua
bash: lua: command not found
 
iSpeedyG@iSpeedyG-PC MINGW64 /c/lua
$ justchecking.lua
/c/lua/justchecking.lua: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token Trying to figure out why i cannot run a lua from cmd line. thinking it has someinthing to do with my docs folder now in one drive.
/c/lua/justchecking.lua: line 1: print(Trying to figure out why i cannot run a lua from cmd line. thinking it has someinthing to do with my docs folder now in one drive.)
 
iSpeedyG@iSpeedyG-PC MINGW64 /c/lua
$ 
**"DEFAULT BASH PROMPT abpve"** 

-------------------------------------------------------------------
````

I have no understanding what happened here. I dont know where I screwed up the path on install. I only created the just checking thing because that was where I placed the Binaries in the beginning right at C:\ but MA_Scripts is in my documents folder and notice when I put it in OneNote it politely just moved the folder to the cloud. Going to see if I can attach a photo of my enviroments. I tried to show as much information as I can. I am running through a course online and tried to do
The run from command line like he does and thats when I found this issue out. I hope it is something simple. I am pretty new to this whole thing and have been on a roller-coaster for a few months hence the reformat and new windows the other day. Thats a longer story. On an added issue at 1st CTRL+L used to select the line. Now it doesnt after I turned sync with github account on. I dont even know where to look. Thanks in advance. There are numbers in front of the code they just dont want to copy for some reason.

```
[Picture of all of this I have pasted][1]
[picture of my PATH][2] 


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWgZF.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fztGU.png
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the commands you tried and the answers you got from the computer. Especially justchecking.lua

Comment: C:\lua>lua lua.justchecking.lua
'lua' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\lua>

Comment: crap didn't know the rules on this. going to re - edit the main post. have too much to type in this amount of characters.

Comment: For texts longer than SO limit (30KBytes) upload them to pastebin.com

Comment: `'lua' is not recognized as an internal or external command` Do you have lua.exe installed?  Maybe you should use `lua54` instead of `lua`?

Comment: i have lua 5.4.2 binaries at my c:\lua folder

Comment: Add c:\lua\bin to the path.  It should be the folder where the file lua.exe exists.

Comment: It has been so long since this question I am sure I got it solved 2 years ago when I asked the question. Not sure if there is a close button for the question.